# understanding ATOI function

Tags: c, atoi

Hi I have a text file which contains the below data

```
ABC00011234567
XYZ00021234567
```

To get the data, i have defined a structure

```
typedef struct data {
 char x[3];
 char y[4];
 char z[7];
} key;
```

in the program what I do is read each line and assign it to the structure

```
unsigned char buf[1024];
fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fptr); 
key *k=(key*)buf;
int y = atoi(k->y)
printf( "y=%d\n",y);`
```

I'm getting the output as

```
y=1123456
y=2123456
```

the output Im expecting is

```
y=1
y=2
```

should I assume, atoi takes the pointer of the string and iterates till EOF is encountered?
what should I do to get the values `1` and `2`?

Comment: fptr is the filepointer , data is read from a file.

Comment: I solved the issue, I wrote my own conversion which inturn uses the atoi fn

Answer (score 2):

[atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) takes a nul-terminated string.  You'll have to add your own terminators to your `key` members if you want to limit the length of data `atoi` parses

Answer (score 2):

You should assume that `atoi()` keeps going until it reaches the end of the string or an invalid character. For example, for the string `"123zzz" it'd return 123.

You should either terminate your strings (put a zero at the end of them) and stop using `atoi()` (e.g. use `strtol()` instead); or write your own conversion that doesn't need a terminated string.

*Note: (in general) `atoi()` should never be used for anything other than writing a compiler, because it does things that don't make sense to normal people (e.g. "0129" is 10 and not 129 because it decides the number is octal and the 9 isn't a valid digit for octal).*

Answer (score 1):

atoi() assumes a zero terminated string. In your case, the string will not be zero-terminated, and thus the data in z is read by atoi after y has been read.

To read just the 4 digits, you can use sscanf:

```
sscanf(k->y,"%4d",&y);
```

Comment: is there any other function which takes the lenght too?

Answer (score 1):

The `atoi` function expects a null-terminated string; you are passing a portion of the char array that has its termination past the boundaries of `key::y`, so `atoi` interprets the entire value as a number. If you would like to stick to your "cookie cutter" method of parsing the key, you need to make a copy, and pass it to `atoi`:

```
char temp[5];
memcpy(temp, k->y, 4);
temp[4] = '\0';
int y = atoi(temp);
```

However, I think that using `fscanf` is a better choice:

```
char x[4];
int y, z;
fscanf(fptr, "%3s%4d%7d", x, &y, &z);
printf("%s %d %d", x, y, z);
```

Comment: Here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/7Illm) with an example that uses `scanf`.